# Formulário não executa update

Tags: php

Criei um formulário de edição, onde coloco no *action* o caminho para o arquivo de update e o botão do tipo submit. Mas clico no botão a página não é redirecionada e nem ocorre o update, não ocorre nada que está no arquivo de update, segue abaixo o código de update, quem tiver sugestões do que está errado agradeço.

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', ' ');
if(!$conexao){
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
} 
$id               = $_GET['id'];
$descricao        = $_POST['descricao'];

$sql  = "UPDATE nome_tabela1 SET descricao1 = '$descricao' where id = '$id'";

$sqlF = "UPDATE nome_tabela2 SET descricao2 = ''$descricao'' where id = '$id'";

$result         = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); 
$result         = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlF);

if ($result) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../home.php'); </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>";     
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Formulário:

```
    <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
    if(!$conexao){
        echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
    } 
    ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="POST" action="php/editar_contrato.php">
       <div class="form-group">
           <?php
              $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = '$id'");
              while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $exibe['id']?>"/>               
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Descrição</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" required="required" value="<?php echo $exibe['cont_descricao'] ?>">
            </div>  
       </div>                                                                               
   </form>
    <?php
      }
    ?> 
   <div class="add-task-row">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" type="submit" value="Salvar" name="salvar">
        <span><p></p></span>
        <a href="contratos.php"><input class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" type="reset" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar"></a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Pode esclarecer melhor o "*não ocorre nada*"? Não é direcionado para a página PHP ou é mas a atualização no banco de dados que não é efetivada?

Comment: Nem nem chega na página aparentemente, pois o update não ocorre e nem ocorre o redirecionamento para a página de sucesso

Comment: Então possivelmente é algum erro no seu formulário. Tem como postar o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que você já verificou que a página existe. O botão submit precisa estar dentro do form

```
  <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
    if(!$conexao){
        echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
    } 
    ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="POST" action="php/editar_contrato.php">
       <div class="form-group">
           <?php
              $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = '$id'");
              while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $exibe['id']?>"/>               
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Descrição</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" required="required" value="<?php echo $exibe['cont_descricao'] ?>">
            </div>  
       </div> 
    <?php
      }
    ?> 
   <div class="add-task-row">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" type="submit" value="Salvar" name="salvar">
        <span><p></p></span>
        <a href="contratos.php"><input class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" type="reset" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar"></a>
   </div>                                                                              
  </form>
```

Comment: Vou ajusta e testar, muito obrigado.